# Mock Restrictions criteria with mockito

Tags: hibernate, spring, service, mockito, restrictions

I gotta say that I'm new to Mockito and TDD.. I'm struggling to find a reason to use it.. especially when I find issues like the following one.. 
I'd like to test a "RegisterUser" method in my UserService class .. I'm using spring mvc 3.0.6, Hibernate, Maven and so on..

```
@Override
public void registerUser(User user, UserRoles userRole) throws DataAccessException, UserExistingException {
    checkExistingUser(user);
    user.addRole(new Role(userRole));
    String password = encryptPassword(user);
    userRepository.makePersistent(user);
    sendWelcomeEmail(user.getFirstname(), user.getUsername(), password, user.getEmail());
}

private void checkExistingUser(User user) throws UserExistingException {
    List<User> users = userRepository.findByCriteria(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("username", user.getUsername()), Restrictions.eq("email", user.getEmail())));
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(users)) {
        User userFound = users.get(0);
        List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (userFound.getUsername().equals(user.getUsername())) {
            fields.add("username");
        }
        if (userFound.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail())) {
            fields.add("email");
        }
        throw new UserExistingException(fields);
    }
}
```

Now to test this stuff I need to mock the "userRepository.findByCriteria .." and I tried the following junit test

```
@Test(expected = UserExistingException.class)
public void registerExistingUserTest() throws DataAccessException, UserExistingException {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername("gfalco77");
    user.setEmail("Giuseppe.falco@gmail.com");
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(user);


    Mockito.when(userRepository.findByCriteria(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("username", user.getUsername()), Restrictions.eq("email", user.getEmail())))).thenReturn(users);
    userService.registerUser(user, UserRoles.ROLE_USER);
    Mockito.verify(userRepository).makePersistent(user);
}
```

But it seems that the "users" list is always empty.. In a previous post I read that Restrictions are not the same object and maybe I have to use Matchers.. but how? And If I use matchers.. is it still valid create a test with something different?

Comment: On your feelings toward Mockito and TDD: I'm pretty new to unit testing and TDD myself, but I almost instantly fell in love with the JUnit+Mockito combo when I started using it - it's a great way to easily perform rigorous tests of your code. What I understand is the point of TDD is that such a development model is intended to make sure that there are ALWAYS tests for ALL your program's features, so you immediately know when your new update breaks something. It's probably not the best development model for every project, but I like to keep that philosophy in mind.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but your test is difficult to write because your service class is mixing business code with data access code. The `findByCriteria` call should be encapsulated into a higher-level method of `UserRepository` like

```
List<User> findByNameOrEmail(String name, String email)
```

You would just have to mock this simple method in your test, and make an actual repository unit test, which tests that the `findByNameOrEmail` works as expected on a test database.

If you UserRepository only expose such generic methods such as `findByCriteria` or `findByQuery`, then it's not really a repository anymore, since the creation of the criteria or the query is of the responsibility of the caller, and not of the repository. Doing that doesn't add much more than using the Hibernate session directly in the business service.

Comment: Yes, it was so obvious... it works now.. The fact is that the UserRepository was extending a GenericHibernateDaoImpl with a findbycriteria predefined.. so it was easy in the service pass the criteria..

Comment: This method should be protected to make it callable by subclasses, but not by external classes. It shouldn't be in the public interface of the repository.